# ruby gsub function in java, replaceAll maybe?

Tags: java, ruby, regex, string, replace

I've been trying to translate this

```
    funcFormat = funcFormat.gsub(/sqrt\((.*)\)/,'Math.sqrt(\1)')
```

to this in java

```
    funcFormat = funcFormat.replaceAll("sqrt((.*))","Math.sqrt($1)");
```

or is there any way of formatting math as text?, for example :

2x^2sqrt(x^3/2) to  2xpow2sqrt(xpow3/2)

thank you, and by the way I'm new in this site.

Comment: `/sqrt\((.*)\)/` is a regular expression.

Comment: Welcome :) Isn't the `^` -> `pow` exactly the same situation as the first? Just replacing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following expression:

```
funcFormat = funcFormat.replaceAll("sqrt\\(([^)]*)\\)", "Math.sqrt($1)");
```

although it seems you don't need regexes here. A simple

```
funcFormat = funcFormat.replace("sqrt", "Math.sqrt");
```

seems to work just as well for your situation.

Comment: oh thank you!, yeah I also need the function between parenthesis after sqrt

Answer (score 1):

While the given example didn't really need a regex, mine *did*. 
 If you do need a regex, the method you're looking for is [`String.replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) (as you mentioned).  Ruby's `String#sub` corresponding java version would be [`String.replaceFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

In summary:

```
              Ruby              |               Java
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
String#sub (regex, replacement) | String.replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)
String#gsub(regex, replacement) | String.replaceAll  (String regex, String replacement)
```